# Javascript — Why does the getAttribute() function not work on certain attributes?

Tags: javascript

Why does the alert display the correct value (which is pl) when i use  `alert(el2.getAttribute("class"));`but does not do so when I use `alert(el2.getAttribute("value"));` (which is supposed to be the value for each option such as sunny... etc).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Allowance updater example</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <label for="weather">Select the weather type today: </label>
<select id="weather">
  <option value="" class = "pl">--Make a choice--</option>
  <option value="sunny" class = "pl">Sunny</option>
  <option value="rainy" class = "pl">Rainy</option>
  <option value="snowing" class = "pl">Snowing</option>
  <option value="overcast" class = "pl">Overcast</option>
</select>

<p></p>
      <script>
          var el = document.querySelector("select");
          var el2 = document.querySelector("option");
          el.addEventListener("click", x);
          function x() {  
          alert(el2.getAttribute("value"));
        alert(el2.getAttribute("class"));
          }
      </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use the value property? `el.value`?

Answer (score 4):

> which is supposed to be the value for each option such as sunny... etc

No. It is supposed to be the value attribute for the particular element that is stored in `e2`.

> ```
> var el2 = document.querySelector("option");
> ```

… and that is the **first** option element in the document.

> ```
> <option value="" class = "pl">
> ```

… which is an empty string.

If you want to get all the options then you need to get them **all** (`querySelectorAll`) and then loop over the resulting list of elements as if it were an array.

Comment: ok thank you, but what if I call the event listener on el2 (option instead) like this el2.addEventListener("click", x); Why doesn't this work (displays nothing in this case)?

Comment: IIRC option elements can't have click events bound to them because of the way their are implemented (also that would still target only the **first** option element)

Answer (score 0):

You can't like this?

```
<script>
      var el = document.querySelector("select");
      el.addEventListener("change", x);
      function x() {  
        alert(el.value);
      }
</script>
```